# How to get the files/folders in directory to show every time I change directory on Linux automatically?

Tags: bash

I'm using [Crunchbang](http://crunchbang.org/) (linux) on a virtual machine and every time I change directory I automatically do an `ls` to check what is there. I'm assuming that it is possible to write a script to make it do this automatically. I'm also assuming it would be a bash script of some kind, but I have maybe once written one so I wouldn't know where to start. Can anyone give me some pointers of how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to `~/.bash_profile`

```sh
foo ()
{
  history 1 >q
  read k <q
  rm q
  set $k
  if [ $2 = cd ]
  then
    ls
  fi
}    
PROMPT_COMMAND=foo
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/.exports)

Comment: PERFECT. You're a star! I had to create a `.bash_profile` as it didn't exist (neither did `.profile`), but this is EXACTLY what I wanted. - and that change is even better :)

Comment: forget it! I put the `{` on the same line as foo() but I changed it and it works :)